# subscribing to multiple compressed image streams via wifi fails

Tags: ros, kinect, compressed

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to send kinect depth and rgb images from a laptop on a robot to a different computer via wifi.

While it is possible to subscribe to 1 stream of compressed images without any problems, I'm unable to subscribe to 2 topics at the same time (e.g. /camera/depth_registered/image_rect/compressedDepth & /camera/rgb/image_color/compressed). At the beginning, when monitoring the frequency of the messages received using *rostopic hz*,  the frame rate is ok (between 10-15 fps). However, after a while (c.a. 10 - 15 seconds) one of the stream starts to receive no messages anymore.

I reduced the compression quality to reduce bandwidth, but this does not help. Furthermore, I looked whether the machines were capable of compressing and decompressing images, and both machines seem to have no difficulties.

Has anyone experienced similar issues in the past and knows a solution.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56989/subscribing-to-multiple-compressed-image-streams-via-wifi-fails/) by [youri](https://answers.ros.org/users/4347/youri/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you had a look at your bandwidth usage, e.g. with iftop? Can you give information about the bandwidth used when subscribing to the rgb stream vs. subscribing to the depth stream vs. both?

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1